# Why is there a gap to other elements when I add an image to the navigation bar in html?

Tags: html, css

right now the HTML file gives me very weird issue when the image is added. When I remove the image, it returns to normal. I want to make the element alignment matches with the image.

[image]

```css
body {
    
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    
}

.top-navigation-bar {

    background-color: #5B9BD5;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    width: inherit;
    height: 50px;

}

.top-navigation-bar img{

    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    border-width: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline;

}

.top-navigation-bar button{

    border-width: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: inherit;
    padding-block: 0;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    border-style: none;
    display: inline;

}

.top-navigation-bar button text{
    
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 95%;
    background-color: inherit;
    display: inline;
    
}

.top-navigation-bar button selected{

    padding: 0;
    height: 90%;
    width: 5%;
    background-color: inherit;
    display: inline;

}

.top-navigation-bar button:hover selected{

    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 90%;
    width: 5%;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline;

}
```

```html
<div class="top-navigation-bar">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/20/20"></img>
    <button href="#">
        <selected></selected>
        <text>Home</text>
    </button>
    <button href="#">
        <selected> </selected>
        <text>Contact</text>
    </button>
    <button>
        <selected> </selected>
        <text>Why DataPredict</text>
    </button>
</div>
```

Ah also, I was trying to make a black bar appear when the mouse hovers over it. So don't change that. But also I could not get that to work either, since it isn't appearing when I hover it. What exactly I'm missing here?

Comment: There are no such elements as `<selected>` or `<text>`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For the `hover` you want to set the `display:block`. 

Comment: For the `navbar`. Can you please add the `icon` as a single image. Because the `width:auto` seems to be odd. 

Answer (score 0):

I edited your HTML and CSS, here are the Enhancements and Features:

1. Flexbox Layout.
2. Responsive and Accessible Navigation.
3. Logo and Navigation Separation.

---

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.top-navigation-bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #5B9BD5;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.logo-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo {
    height: 40px; /* Adjust based on your logo */
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
}

.nav-link {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

.nav-link:hover, .nav-link:focus {
    background-color: white;
    color: #5B9BD5;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DataPredict</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/datapredict/icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="top-navigation-bar">
        <div class="logo-container">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/CmRSk7R/6896337931640837502-512.png" alt="DataPredict Logo" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="nav-links">
            <a href="home.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            <a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Why DataPredict</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```